# VB.NET LINQ Group By Into Select New cannot access class members BC30456

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to convert some C# code to VB.NET from the following tutorial that shows how to generate a HTML table with row group headings using LINQ Group By Into:

https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/grouping-data-with-linq-and-mvc/

The C# code works as advertised, but my VB.NET conversion has an issue.

The working C# line of code I'm having trouble with in VB.NET:

```
// Group the books by Genre
var booksGrouped = from b in books
                   group b by b.Genre into g
                   select new Group<string, Book> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };
```

Visual Studio is reporting "g.Key" is:

```
string IGrouping<string, Book>.Key
```

In VB.NET, the two classes, Group and Book look like this:

```
Public Class Group(Of K, T)
    Public Property Key As K
    Public Property Values As IEnumerable(Of T)
End Class

Public Class Book
    Public Title As String
    Public Author As String
    Public Genre As String
    Public Price As Decimal
End Class
```

And the above C# line of code as VB.NET:

```
Dim booksGrouped = From b In books Group b By b.Genre Into g = Group
                   Select New Group(Of String, Book) With {.Key = g.Key, .Values = g}
```

*Note: I had to add the "= Group" to the 'Into' clause otherwise "g" has the error "BC36594: Definition of method 'g' is not accessible in this context."*

Visual Studio is reporting that "g.Key" is now an IEnumerable:

```
BC30456: 'Key' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(of Book)'.
```

So C# is seeing the IGroup interface, and VB.NET is seeing an IEnumerable.

I love the simplicity of the solution offered in the tutorial and would really like to implement this in VB.NET, does anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

Many thanks.

The sample data in VB.NET is

```vb
Dim books As New List(Of Book)

books.Add(New Book With {.Author = "Douglas Adams", .Title = "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", .Genre = "Fiction", .Price = 159.95D})
books.Add(New Book With {.Author = "Scott Adams", .Title = "The Dilbert Principle", .Genre = "Fiction", .Price = 23.95D})
books.Add(New Book With {.Author = "Douglas Coupland", .Title = "Generation X", .Genre = "Fiction", .Price = 300D})
books.Add(New Book With {.Author = "Walter Isaacson", .Title = "Steve Jobs", .Genre = "Biography", .Price = 219.25D})
books.Add(New Book With {.Author = "Michael Freeman", .Title = "The Photographer's Eye", .Genre = "Photography", .Price = 195.5D})
```

Comment: Key has to be Title, Author, Genre, or Price

Comment: `Dim booksGrouped = books.GroupBy(Function(bk) bk.Genre).Select(Function(g) New Group(Of String, Book) With {.Key = g.Key, .Values = g})` does not show any problems.

Comment: I added the translation of the sample data for anyone's convenience.

Comment: Substituted Andrew's code and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare who is going to be your key. By your code is supposed `Genre`. So, you need to use grouping functions as Morton suggest or you have to identify a  *“key”*  for your grouped `List(of Book)`

The code below shows how:

```
    Dim booksGrouped = From b In books
                       Group b By Key = b.Genre Into g = Group
                       Select New Group(Of String, Book) With {.Key = Key, .Values = g}


    For Each current In booksGrouped
        For Each value In current.Values
            With value
                Console.WriteLine("Key:" & current.Key & "value: " & Strings.Join({ .Genre, .Author, .Price, .Title}, " - "))
            End With
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be explicit about the key - the C# code specifies "g.Key", but C# is figuring out that it must be "Genre":

```
Dim booksGrouped = From b In books
    Group b By b.Genre Into g = Group
    Select New Group(Of String, Book) With {
        .Key = Genre,
        .Values = g
    }
```